# Ionic angular dropdown list

Tags: angular, list, ionic-framework

I have a problem with dropdown list. I don’t understand how to expand the list and hide it. Does anyone have any ideas what needs to be added, preferably without using third-party libraries?

My idea was that we have a list, and to the right of each is a button. When you click on the button, a list opens under the list on which the button was clicked

```
list0 ----- button0
list1 ----- button1 (click)
- list1.1
- list1.2
list3 ----- button3
list4 ----- button4 (click)
- list4.1
- list4.2
- list4.3
```

`services.page.html`:

```html
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <ion-list *ngFor="let e of services">
    <ion-item-divider>
      <ion-label>{{e.Name}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item-divider>
    <div *ngIf="e.ListServices != null">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let g of e.ListServices">
        <ion-label>{{g.Description}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

JSON:

```json
[
   {
      "GuidServicesId":"9647d79b-2b10-4e7d-bd26-199cda4da4aa",
      "Name":"asd",
      "ListServices":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "GuidServicesId":"1760d99a-fe30-4573-885f-1e0dabc97c6e",
      "Name":"asda",
      "ListServices":[
         {
            "GuidListSevicesId":"9b45ffe1-7a50-430b-b1ba-57d24e4ae877",
            "Description":"testlistr",
            "consultationRequests":[
               
            ],
            "ServicesId":"1760d99a-fe30-4573-885f-1e0dabc97c6e"
         },
         {
            "GuidListSevicesId":"fec5b5ca-34ad-41bc-aa1d-a0727d3f48df",
            "Description":"asdasdas",
            "consultationRequests":[
               
            ],
            "ServicesId":"1760d99a-fe30-4573-885f-1e0dabc97c6e"
         },
      ]
   }
]
```

[Ideally, do it like this, but there is almost no hope to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6OSq.png)

Comment: My idea was that we have a list, and to the right of each is a button. When you click on the button, a list opens under the list on which the button was clicked
list0 ----- button0
list1 ----- button1 (click)
- list1.1
- list1.2
list3 ----- button3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to utilize ngIf, as in

```
<button (click)="showList=!showList">Click me</button>
<div *ngIf="showList"> 
   <ion-list  *ngFor="let e of services">
     ...
   </ion-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow identify that this button is responsible for this list. Just works for everything

Comment: Yes, you could name the variables something more specific.  Or set a function that it calls where you could manage logic for mulitple buttons/lists...